# reCAPTCHA v2 with PHP cURL - e-mail not being sent/unintended output on page

Tags: php, curl, recaptcha

I'm automatically rendering the widget on one page. On the page where the values are supposed to be using POST, my PHP code is:

```
  <?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])):
        if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])):

            $data = array(
                        'secret' => "secret-key",
                        'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']
                    );

            $verify = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
            curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
            curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $response = curl_exec($verify);

            var_dump($response);

            if(var_dump($response)->success):
                //contact form submission code
                $name = !empty($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:'';
                $email = !empty($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'';
                $phone = !empty($_POST['phonenumber'])?$_POST['phonenumber']:'';
                $message = !empty($_POST['comment'])?$_POST['comment']:'';

               $to = 'jdoe@mail.com';
               $subject = 'Personal Message from '.$name;
               $htmlContent = "
                    <h1>Contact Us - Message</h1>
                    <p style=\"font-size: 1.5em;\"><span style=\"font-weight: bolder;\">Name: </span>".$name."</p>
                    <p style=\"font-size: 1.5em;\"><span style=\"font-weight: bolder;\">Email: </span>".$email."</p>
                    <p style=\"font-size: 1.5em;\"><span style=\"font-weight: bolder;\">Phone Number: </span>".$phone."</p>
                    <p style=\"font-size: 1.5em;\"><span style=\"font-weight: bolder;\">Message: </span>".$message."</p>";
                    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
                    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
                    // More headers
                    $headers .= 'From:'.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
                    //send email
                    @mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers);

                    $succMsg = '<em>Your contact request submitted successfully.</em>';
                echo $succMsg;
            else:
                $errMsg = '<em>Robot verification failed, please try again.</em>';
                echo $errMsg;
            endif;
        else:
            $errMsg = '<em>Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.</em>';
            echo $errMsg;
        endif;
    else:
        $errMsg = 'Something went wrong with the submission';
        $succMsg = '';
        echo $errMsg;
    endif;
?>
```

The message that is outputted on the posted page when I submit the form is this:

string(95) "{ "success": true, "challenge_ts": "2016-12-12T15:38:25Z", "hostname": "mywebsite.com" }" string(95) "{ "success": true, "challenge_ts": "2016-12-12T15:38:25Z", "hostname": "mywebsite.com" }" Robot verification failed, please try again.

I'm not quite sure what the string(95) means and why it outputs the JSON information, when it seems like success is true. I'm somehow not getting the fundamentals of why this page outputs this. Also the e-mail doesn't end up getting sent as well, which is the other problem.

Comment: This is redundant: `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])):` - can be simplified to just `if ( ! empty( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ):`.

Comment: The answer to your question: `var_dump( $response );` in your code is causing this to be output.  That's the value of `$response` from Google Recaptcha.  To **use it** simply `$response = @json_decode($response); if ( $response && ! empty( $response->success ) ) { // Yay! Success }`.

Comment: I followed your instruction and it seems to work. I understand taking out the var_dump function, but don't understand putting the "@" before the json_decode function. What does the "->" in the $response->success do in the empty function?

Comment: Disregard my previous post, I understand.